# How to get logged on user id and insert to another table in PHP

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

```
<?php
include 'check_login.php';

if(isset($_POST['apply']))    
    session_start();

$uid = $_SESSION['user_index'];
$leavetype = $_POST['leavetype'];
$fromdate = $_POST['fromdate'];
$todate = $_POST['todate'];
$description = $_POST['description'];
$status=0;
$isread=0;

if($fromdate > $todate){
    $error=" ToDate should be greater than FromDate ";
}

include '../db_config/connection.php';

$sql = "SELECT * FROM user_info where user_index = '$uid'";
$result = $conn->query($sql);

if($result->num_rows > 0) {
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        $uid = $row['user_index'];
        header("location:../add_leave.php?msg=Leave for $uid is not available&ent_id=$uid");
    }
} else {
    include '../db_config/connection.php';
    $sql = "INSERT INTO tblleaves(leavetype, todate, fromdate, description, status, isRead, user_index)
              VALUES ('$leavetype', '$fromdate', '$todate', '$description', '$status', '$isread', '$uid')";

    if($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
        header("location: apply_leave.php?message=$leavetype have been requested");
    } else {
        $error = $conn->error;
        header("location: add_leave.php?err=$error");
    }

    $conn->close();
}

$conn->close();
?>
```

I've been working on a Leave management and on the User side the user needs to apply for a leave but I am unable to get the `ID` of the current logged in user to be added to another table called `tblleaves` the table where the user id resides is `user_info`. I can add other data to `tblleaves` but not the user id.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to reorganize this script and you aren't checking things properly. You also have an SQL injection issue:

```
<?php
# Add this to the top, don't add it as an "if" conditional
session_start();
# Add this once and also at the top, regardless of if you use it
include('../db_config/connection.php');
# Same
include('check_login.php');

# I would make a function for this (move to it's own page and include it)
function getUserInfo($uid,$conn)
{
    $uid    = (is_numeric($uid))? $uid : false;
    if(!$uid)
        return false;
    # Fetch
    $result = $conn->query("SELECT * FROM user_info where user_index = '$uid'");
    if($result->num_rows > 0) {
        $row = $result->fetch_assoc();
        return $row;
    }

    return [];
}

# Create a function to add the user's leave BUT YOU NEED TO BIND PARAMETERS
# HERE! WHAT YOU HAVE IS NOT SAFE!!
function addUserLeave($uid,$array,$conn)
{
    # Question marks are placeholders for values
    $sql = "INSERT INTO tblleaves(leavetype, todate, fromdate, description, status, isRead, user_index) VALUES (?,?,?,?,1,1,?)";
    # Prepare the statement
    $query = $conn->prepare($sql);
    # Bind the values to question marks in the statement, use the first parameter in this
    # method to indicate to the method what each value type each should be
    $query->bind_param('ssssssi',$array['leavetype'], $array['fromdate'], $array['todate'], $array['description'],$uid);
    # Now run the query
    return $query->execute($sql);
}
# Set a default error
$error = 'You must submit the form';
# You have to use braces to cover all the other assigned post values
if(isset($_POST['apply'])) {
    $uid         = $_SESSION['user_index'];
    $leavetype   = $_POST['leavetype'];
    $fromdate    = $_POST['fromdate'];
    $todate      = $_POST['todate'];
    $description = $_POST['description'];
    # I have no idea how these are used, they seem pointless based
    # on your sample script
    $status      =
    $isread      = 0;
    # Check date
    if($fromdate > $todate) {
        $error = '"To" date should be greater than the "from" date';
    }
    # If you have an error on date, it doesn't make sense to keep going
    # with the script, so use else
    else {
        # Fetch user info here
        $userInfo = getUserInfo($uid,$conn);
        # Check that there is a value here
        if(!empty($userInfo['user_index'])) {
            # Redirect AND exit
            header("Location: ../add_leave.php?err=Leave for {$uid} is not available&ent_id={$uid}");
            exit;
        }
        else {
            # Run the function to insert
            $added = addUserLeave($uid,$_POST,$conn);
            if($added) {
                # Redirect AND exit
                header("Location: apply_leave.php?message={$leavetype} have been requested");
                exit;
            }
            else
                $error = $conn->error;
        }
    }
}
# Default is to redirect
header("location: add_leave.php?err={$error}");
```